# When should a free() implementation give memory back to the OS?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I'm writing a simple malloc implementation for a college project. One of the tasks is to sometimes give back freed memory to the OS (the example given was of a process using say 1GB malloc-ed memory during a period, and afterwards it only uses 100MB memory until it terminates), however I'm not sure how to implement this. I was thinking of periodically checking the amount of memory the process has allocated and the amount freed and, if possible, give back some of the freed pages to the OS, but I'm not sure if this is an efficient approach.

EDIT: I didn't realize when I first wrote this, but the way I worded this is too vague. By "unused memory" I'm talking specifically about freed one.

Comment: You can't always give it back. If you asked for a 1GB slab and used *any* of it, then you're stuck with it. This is where memory fragmentation becomes an issue. That being said, if you ask for 1GB and only use 100MB, then the OS knows this and probably hasn't actually allocated the rest per-se, it's just reserved, as virtual memory is in play here. You can "give it back" but I'm not sure the OS actually cares if it's thinly provisioned. This of course depends on the OS you're using and how it handles virtual memory.

Comment: @KamilCuk I haven't thought too much about it, but I had in mind some sort of function that's triggered by the first malloc call and re-calls itself every x seconds. The function could look to every block's metadata to see if its used\unused.

Comment: @KamilCuk The metadata I use in my malloc implementation to keep track of blocks. I think I got a bit lost in translation in my question, by unused memory I meant freed.

Comment: Since you have to implement your custom `malloc`, I assume you'll have to implement also your custom `free`. So why bothering with a synchronous check when `free` represents the perfect asynchronous hook? Whenever `free` is called check the amount of used memory, and if there's something that can be released (whatever is your criteria) just release it.

Comment: "I was thinking of periodically checking the amount of memory" - you wouldn't do this periodically, but when an allocation operation (`free`) occurs. And probably, you'd return a chunk at the time you detected that such a chunk was free, rather than scanning the heap. There are of course variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking the OS for memory or returning it back are (relatively) expensive operation because they require a context switch user/kernel and back. For that reason, in most implementations, the malloc call only asks for large chunks and internally allocates from those chunks, and manages freed memory with a *free blocks list*. In that case, it only returns memory to the OS when a full chunk is present in the free list.

For a custom implementation, the rule for returning memory to the system is up to the programmer (you...).